# How can we see deamon proceses in Android?

Tags: adb, root-access

How can we see all the daemon processes with their statuses on our android device?

Reason for asking is that recently I came to know that `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) is a daemon process running on our Android device. Whenever we install the Android SDK adb server is installed which interacts between the client (IDE or the shell) and the daemon process running on Android (correct me if I have mistaken). So specifically, I want to view this daemon process's status and find more details about it like what port it is listening to.

My device is running Android 4.0.4 (ICS). Device is rooted of course. I have installed terminal emulator and busybox.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several process monitoring tools available on *Google Play*. One of them is [OS Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/os-monitor/com.eolwral.osmonitor), which is very likely to help you out with your issue:

[image: OS Monitor process list] [image: OS Monitor TCP/IP]
<sup>OS Monitor: Process list, list of open ports (souce: Google Play)</sup>

As the two screenshots visualize, you can see all running processes as well as network connections including used ports and current status.

Of course, you could also make use of command-line tools like `ps` (to show running processes) and `netstat` (to show open ports) from within your terminal app (or via `adb shell`). Together with `grep`, that might be even faster, as you can filter out unwanted entries (e.g. `netstat | grep adb`).